# What is "Yindy"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, songs

I've heard a song "Yindy" by "Fiddler's Green". Here's the first couplet and a refrain from it:

```
My mother she took me to the preacher.
She told me that he will be my teacher.
My father he thought that I was lazy.
He drank and drank till he went crazy.
My sister she showed me all her loving.
And I? I just gave her nothing.
My brother was like a little donky.
His face was just like from a monkey.

Yindy let me go, take me back to the streets I know.
Yindy let me go, take me back to the flow.
Yindy let me go, take me back to the streets I know.
Yindy let me go, take me back to the flow.
```

I can't understand neither google, what is Yindy and what does it mean here. Need an explanation.

Comment: Hello, Waldemar, the downvote to your question indicates your question is not useful and doesn't show any research efforts. Interpretation of song lyrics is off-topic. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. [Meaning of Yindi](http://www.meaning-of-names.com/australian-names/yindi.asp).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because interpreting lyrics is generally off-topic.

Comment: I was't asking for interpretation. I just didn't know, what is Yindy. Now I know, it's a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it somehow correlates with the meaning of the name itself. In Australian, the name Yindi means - the sun.The name Yindi originated as an Australian name. The name Yindi is most often used as a girl name or female name. [http://www.meaning-of-names.com/australian-names/yindi.asp#ixzz4EHc0sAC0]
Maybe it is used as a metaphor. All the relationship with the relatives seem to be dull, the sun, the change may help to enjoy the life.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Rathony's comment. I could not google this is a name because it's written as "YindY" instead of "Yindi". Now I've got it.